# How do I test when a player moves forward?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm working on a one command creation called Magical Weapons. There's a weapon called the Reverse Crystal, and it basically reverses the movement. If you move +1 on the x-axis, you are teleported -2 on the x-axis, and so on and so forth. But how do I test for when a player moves, like +1 X or -1 Z?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: @Frank I didn't really try because I had no idea where to start... sorry!

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek You are completely missing the point here. This is definitely not easy to do, which makes "Write my commands for me" questions plain rude without putting in effort first. Furthermore, due to the nature of Arqade/SE, we require a *full* answer, which makes brainstorming (which would actually help the asker) impossible.

Comment: @MrLemon oh, ok

Answer (score 1):

I made a movement detection system a while ago that I think could be useful for this. You can use it as a reference or modify it to fit your creation.

You will need 1 repeating command block and 15 chain command blocks connected to it (all set to always active). Here are the commands: https://pastebin.com/445LRfFz

And here is the system in action:
[image]

it stores the player's current position into some scoreboard objectives (x and z). Then, it constantly compares the player's x objective to the player's prev_x objective to see if there are any changes. If x is greater than prev_x, that means the player has moved towards positive x. I also made it so it tags the player with "x+" and then says "x+" in chat.

Answer (score 0):

I redid the command blocks and got a much better, but still not excellent solution:

[image: Look! Some orange squares!]

Now, what the command blocks have:

1:

```
/testfor @e[type=ArmorStand]
```

2:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ testfor @e[type=ArmorStand,r=0]
```

3:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~
```

4:

```
/kill @e[type=ArmorStand]
```

5:

```
/tp @a @e[type=ArmorStand]
```

Notes:

- Sorry for not using the 1.9 Command blocks, because I really don't know how to do this with them.